# How to disable swiping up on a sheet, which makes it slightly larger for a second

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

If I have a sheet in SwiftUI with a set presentation detent, users are still able to drag the top of it slightly beyond the height of the set detent, increasing the frame of the sheet for a split second. Is there any way to disable this / fix the size of the sheet so this doesn't happen?

```
SomeView()
  .presentationDetents[.height(200)]
  .sheet(isPresented: $isPresented) { ... }
```

Let me know if I need to provide a video of what I'm talking about.

Comment: Why is this undesirable? Does it cause layout issues with your view? Perhaps you should fix that instead?

Comment: Its a design preference in my use case.

Answer (score 2):

One way I thought of is to add a high-priority drag gesture to the view. Make sure the view covers the whole sheet, so that the system gesture to expand the sheet does not get triggered.

Example:

```
// inside .sheet(...) { ... }
Text("Bar")
    .ignoresSafeArea()
    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
    .background(.white)
    // For Text, the above modifiers make sure it covers the whole sheet
    // Make sure your view covers the whole sheet in your own way

    .presentationDetents([.height(200)])
    .highPriorityGesture(DragGesture())
```

Of course, if your sheet has other drag gestures, they won't work. If you can't avoid that, it's probably better to write your own sheet view. [Example](https://medium.com/mop-developers/custom-sheets-for-swiftui-70b36370f514).

This only works if you only have one presentation detent. If you have multiple presentation detents, the user cannot switch to another detent with the system gesture. You can provide an alternative way to switch detents though. On the other hand, the user can still dismiss the sheet by tapping outside of the sheet.

If the sheet contains a scroll view that covers the whole sheet, you can instead do:

```
.presentationContentInteraction(.scrolls)
```

Comment: My sheet has a wheel picker on it, which complicates things. Is there a way given that?

Comment: @NicolasGimelli II tried it and the picker still works. Apparently the picker doesn't count as a having a "drag gesture". The drag gestures added by `.gesture(DragGesture()...)` does count however.